# Using a unique key when mapping data - react, mui react jsx. javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I attempted to map data through a jsx component using an array full of objects. I believe my self that I used a correct unique key value pair. I'm getting an error saying that I need to use a unique value pair. I am confused because each reference of dat that I am using has a unique paring due to it being the name that is unique to it self. In order for me to render the picture The value pairs need to have a more unique a approach I assume. what I tried to do was use the different names of the data points to represent the unique key and data pairs. Using them resulted in error and the images not loading on the render when running the page.

```
[
    { id: 'lOGITECH', src: logitech},
    { id: 'DUCKY_KEYBOARDS', src: ducky}, 
    { id: 'TWTICH', src: twitch},
    { id: 'HYPERX', src: hyper}, 
    { id: 'COORSAIR', src: coorsair}, 
    { id: 'ASTRO', src: astro}, 
    { id: 'CALIBAR_VAPE', src: vape},
    { id: 'THERMALTAKE', src: thermaltake}, 
    { id: 'NUPHY', src: nuphy}, 
    { id: 'DISCORD', src: discord}
]

{
  logos.map(({ id, src }) => (
    <box sx={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <img
        key={src}
        width="75px"
        height="75px"
      // figure out how to do the box shadow style it is listed as "paper on mui. "
      />
      <p key={id}></p>
    </box>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Only the outer element should have a key, also your img tag is missing an alt value

Answer (score 3):

Only the outer element needs an unique `key`, use the following:

```
logos.map(({ id, src }) => (
    <box key={id} sx={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <img
            width="75px"
            height="75px"
        />
    </box>
))
```